# MVC 4 WebGrid C# Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I am trying to populate a web grid view with static data but I am not having any luck.

I always get the error:

```
"A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed".
```

I understand where the error is coming from by setting up breakpoints. Basically, when the page is loaded up, the code never accesses the Account() function. Since it doesn't do that, allFiles is never initialized and returned.

Would the best way to do this be to call Action() from the View and initialize all files? I've read other questions regarding the same error but no one highlighted the fact that the code is not accessing the controller function.

Here is the Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Account()
    {
        FileModel file = new FileModel();
        List<FileModel> allFiles = new List<FileModel>();
        file.FileID = "1";
        file.UserID = "1";
        var data = allFiles;
        return View(data);
    }
```

Here is the Model

```
   public class FileModel
{
    public string FileID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string AddedOn { get; set; }
    public int Downloads { get; set; }
    public int Show { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the View

```
    @model IEnumerable<GridTest1.Models.FileModel>
    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Files";
       WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
    }
    <h2>People</h2>
    @grid.GetHtml(columns: new [] {
         grid.Column("FileID"),
         grid.Column("UserID")
    })
```

Comment: allFiles.Add(file); ? Is this line what you missing?

Comment: I've tried it with and without it. It technically should not give you an error even if it is an empty list. That shouldnt be the issue. The issue is the Account Action Result is never returned. No idea why

Comment: Try IList or IEnumerable instead of List...just a guess. Like List<FileModel> allFiles make it IEnumerable<FileModel> allFiles

Comment: Nope i tried that too but no luck. I just find it really word that it doesn't go in the account function when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

your controller coding order is wrong. Check the following code

```
    public ActionResult Account()
    {
        // Assign a value to class
        FileModel file = new FileModel();
        file.FileID = "1";
        file.UserID = "1";
        file.FileName = "Text.txt";
        file.AddedOn = "AddedOn";

        // Create instance for all file
        List<FileModel> allFiles = new List<FileModel>();

        // Add file model to list
        allFiles.Add(file);

        // Pass the file list to view
        return View(allFiles);
    }
```

View

```
@model List<GridTest1.Models.FileModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Files";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

@grid.GetHtml(columns: new[] {
         grid.Column("FileID"),
         grid.Column("UserID"),
         grid.Column("FileName"),
         grid.Column("AddedOn"),
    })
```

This will work